# Simple example in Extjs6.5 Fiddle not working

Tags: extjs6

I'm trying to generate a basic project with a store "Pathstore" and data "data.json" in my Extjs6.5 Fiddle but it goes not well.I'm not sure what paths I need to specify in my application to load.How can I do for this?

Thanks in advance, Ben

Here's the the fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25vm

I add console.log in my store and I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few things:

- You don't need to use requires here
- Your PathStore has a lot of unneeded configs in the proxy config *(see fiddle below)*
- You didn't have a data model specified.
- There were some errors in your JSON config.
- the folder is `store.PathStore.js` so it was not required to use `app.store.PathStore`

I organized your fiddle a little bit better and made it working. Here is a working version of you fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/271g